# Are the temperature coefficients used for resistance in electricity and length in mechanics the same?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, electrical-resistance, material-science

I just noticed that the formulas for change in resistance feel like they were derived from formulas regarding change in length which are related to thermal stress in mechanics, and I have studied both. My question is, are the temperature coefficients for both lessons conceptually the same?  I'm just curious because of the wordings some textbooks used which make them feel different. In electricity, the term temperature coefficient of resistance is used. In mechanics, the term coefficient of thermal linear expansion is used. How much are they the same and different? Can values between the two be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not.

From the Engineering Toolbox site, the temperature coefficient for change in resistance for aluminum is 3.8 x 10$^{-3}$ 1/C and the temperature coefficient of expansion is 21-24 x 10$^{-6}$1/C. So they can't be used interchangeably.

> How are they different, when the unit is suppose to be the same since
> the physical property gets cancelled anyway? Could you be more
> specific with how values are different, for example between the
> temperature coefficient of length and resistance? Maybe also why they
> are different?

They are different because the temperature coefficient for electrical resistance is an electrical property of a material whereas the temperature coefficient of expansion for the same material is a physical property of the material.

Just because the units of two properties are the same doesn't mean they are the same properties. For example, both heat capacity and entropy have units of J/K but that doesn't mean they are the same thing.  They are not the same thing.

Also just because there may be some correlation between different properties doesn't mean the properties are the same (interchangeable). For example, it is well known that metals have both high the electrical conductivity and high thermal conductivity. But electrical and thermal conductivity can't be used interchangeably because one is an electrical property whereas the other is a thermal property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you link to what you were referring to in the Engineering Toolbox site? From what I know, you are referring to resistivity when it comes to Ohm-m.

Comment: @AndroidV11 Sure. https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/resistivity-conductivity-d_418.html. https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html

Comment: I am referring to the temperature coefficient as mentioned in your link. To refer to my original post, I did not mention the word resistivity at all so I'm sure it's not the 2.6 x 10−8 Ohm.m you are saying. Rather it is the temperature coefficient to the right of that value, 3.8 x 10-3 (1/oC) .

Comment: Oops sorry. I looked at the wrong column. I will correct. But the values are nontheless different.

Comment: How are they different, when the unit is suppose to be the same since the physical property gets cancelled anyway? Could you be more specific with how values are different, for example between the temperature coefficient of length and resistance? Maybe also why they are different? Thank you.

Comment: @AndroidV11 I've updated my answer to respond. I'm afraid that's the best I can do.

Comment: @AndroidV11 Has my updated answer satisfactorily answered your question?

Comment: Yes, I just waited a little more for other answers but it does.